# Android: WiFi and Mobile radio bit rate (BPS)

Tags: android, wifi, rate

I want to figure out the device's wifi and mobile radio bit per second ratio.

Where/how can I get those numbers?

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

You can call [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) getConnectionInfo() which will return a [WifiInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html) which will contain all the info you can get about Wifi.

Use [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to get mobile and other network stats, which may not have all the information you're looking for.